# Django print table

Tags: django

I have simple question, but I do not know how to solve it. Namely printing database table, I would like to print also index number, for instance:

```
{% for n in names %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ n }} </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to have output like this:

1. John
2. Peter

I tried to type in sth like this: {% i = 0 %} and then increase i and print it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See for loop index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Quoting docs:

```
Variable         Description
forloop.counter  The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)
forloop.counter0 The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)
```

For your code:

```
{% for n in names %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ forloop.counter }} {{ n }} </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forloop.counter`

```
{% for n in names %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
       <td>{{ n }} </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `{{ forloop.counter }}` as specified in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#for)